# My ubuntu 22.04.2 wont boot after successful LUKS decryption

Tags: boot, encryption, luks

my disk is encrypted using LUKS and everytime I open my pc I always need to provide the write password before I can log in into my device, so as usual I open my pc ready to work, and as usual I was greeted by the same  input that is asking for my passwords, at first I got it wrong and expectedly it gave me an error message bit when I finally got the password right I notified that  even though it was successful only after a few seconds the preloader stopped spinning so as usual I waited. unexpectedly It stayed there  more than an hour, it didn't boot so I've tried to boot it but I always end up in the same scenario. I just can't get out because after a successful password my device freezes, and I just need to get my personal data at least.

Comment: Boot your computer using an Ubuntu live installation USB. Use the "Try Ubuntu" option. Decrypt your LUKS encrypted system partition from the terminal. Try to mount it. If it does not mount, check for file system corruption. Finally [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1501841/edit) and copy and paste all the output and errors from the terminal. You can search for how to do each step in this site of via Google.